# Export SSMS database connections to a new version

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just installed SSMS 2012 and realized it didn't copy my database list (the one that appears on the 'Connect to Server' dialog).

I have a ton of entries there, is there any way I can export them to the new version of SSMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the registered servers window open "Database Engine" and right click on Local Server Groups.  Select Tasks, then "Previously Registered Servers".  This should import them.

Comment: This didn't work in my case because I didn't have them as registered servers, they just showed up in the dropdown based on some MRU logic I suppose.

Comment: Anyway, I manually added them all today, so I will mark this as an answer until someone comes along with an answer that would have worked in my case.  Thanks!

Comment: Those are polled from the network and the registry (mostly from the network). There are a ton of reasons that list doesn't populate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this in >=2019: Now if you install a new version of SMSS (at least starting with v18) it'll ask you during setup whether you want to import settings from the previous version. If you choose to import them the server list will be imported too. Beware though that you'll need to re-type passwords, saved passwords won't be moved over.